# Segmentation Fault in objective C code

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, crash, segmentation-fault

After I added `[self display]` message in the subclass `+display` method I get a Segmentation Fault. I don't understand why. Please analyze the whole code before saying that the code should infinite loop. The output before adding the above message is:

```
2013-10-15 22:24:30.978 Polymorphism2[657:707] <A1: 0x7fd038c09d00>
2013-10-15 22:24:30.981 Polymorphism2[657:707] <A1: 0x7fd038c09d00>
2013-10-15 22:24:30.981 Polymorphism2[657:707] 10 
2013-10-15 22:24:30.982 Polymorphism2[657:707] 60  
2013-10-15 22:24:30.982 Polymorphism2[657:707] I'm not multiplying this right now 
2013-10-15 22:24:30.983 Polymorphism2[657:707] Superclass!!
```

This is ok. But after adding the above message `[self display]`, it should be outputting one more line right before `"Superclass!!"` line. It should be

```
2013-10-15 22:24:30.983 Polymorphism2[657:707] Subclass!!.
```

Here's the code of the superclass

```
@interface Abc: NSObject 

- (void)calculate:(int)x;
- (void)calculate2:(int)x;
+ (void)display;

@end

@implementation Abc

- (void)calculate:(int)x{
    NSLog(@"%@",self);
    NSLog(@"%d",x);
    [self calculate:x];
    [self calculate2:x];
}

- (void)calculate2:(int)x{
    NSLog(@"%d",x*10);
}

+ (void)display{
    [self display];
    NSLog(@"Superclass!!");
}

@end
```

And of the subclass

```
@implementation A1

- (void)start{
    NSLog(@"%@",self);

    [super calculate:10]; 
}

- (void)calculate:(int)x{ 
    NSLog(@"%d",x+50);
}

- (void)calculate2:(int)x{// Overriding
    NSLog(@"I'm not multiplying this right now");
}

+ (void)display{
    NSLog(@"Subclass");
}

- (void)callClassMethod{
    [Abc display];
}

@end
```

Finally, the main

```
int main(){
    A1 *obj= [[A1 alloc] init]; //Subclass object
    [obj start];
    [obj callClassMethod];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call

```
[Abc display];
```

if will call the `+display` method of `Abc`, in which context `self` is resolved as the class `Abc`.

Therefore

```
[self display]
```

is resolved into

```
[Abc display]
```

resulting in an infinite loop.

In other words, if you invoke `[Abc display]`, there's no reason for assuming `self` to be resolved to a subclass, like `A1`.

Comment: But then the output doesn't reflect an infinite loop.What the console does is displaying the output up till "im not multiplying this right now" and then gives Segmentation fault. Pls run this on ur computer

Comment: Why does the code output Segmentation Fault in this case. It should loop infinitely